# Finding the direction of the arrows in the phase portrait

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have been having difficulties finding the direction:

The system of ODEs is:

$$ \begin{cases}
x' = -x, & x(0)  =x_0\\
        y'=-2y, & y(0) = y_0\\ \end{cases} $$

which I know its direction can be sketched as $y(x) = cx^2$.

I've plotted it online, and all arrows point towards (inwards) the origin (since $(0,0)$ is the equilibrium point), but for example, for $x,y>0$ then there would be some arrows pointing outwards (when computing the derivative). Can anyone illustrate the process? Or let me know what I don't understand.

Comment: Giving $V = \frac 12\left(x^2+2y^2\right)$ we have $\nabla V =- \left(\begin{array}{c} -x\\ -2y\end{array}\right)$ so $\left(\begin{array}{c} x\\ 2y\end{array}\right)$ is the normal vector to $V$ at each point. Now making $V = C$....

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is $x=x_0e^{-t}$, $y=y_0e^{-2t}$. The absolute values of both decreases as $t$ increases, so the arrows point towards the origin. There’s not really much more to it than that. Eliminating $t$ loses this information, which is why you can’t tell from the implicit trajectory equation $y_0x^2=x_0^2y$ which way the arrows should point.